# How to get an only element from the MatchCollection

Tags: c#, regex, collections

I know that there is always only one element in `MatchCollection`:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("1234");
MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches("fjasij 1234 gdsgds");
Console.WriteLine(matches.Count);
string s = ?;
```

How to assign this one element to the variable `string s`  without `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why use a `MatchCollection` then? Just get a single `Match`:

```
var match = reg.Match("fjasij 1234 gdsgds");
```

Comment: +1 for nice Regex API usage. Maybe you meant `reg.Match("fjasij 1234 gdsgds").Value`. Or specify the type of `match` explicitly, to avoid confusion. OP want's to have a string as result, as far as I can see.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Well, this returns a `Match` instance. OP can do whatever they like with it :)

Answer (score 6):

```
string s = matches[0];
```

Note that this *will* fail if you have zero matches.